Where is the correct JPEG/JFIF/Exif format specification?
I try to find the correct format specification for JPEG/JFIF/Exif, etc.
I first checked Where can I get free specifications of JPEG/JFIF/EXIF/etc?, but Chrome prevents me to download all the PDF files by showing:

can't be downloaded securely


...implying the files contain viruses.
I then have to use Google and find some more, as below:

https://jpeg.org/jpeg/index.html
https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf
https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA_TR-98_1st_edition_june_2009.pdf

So I totally get confused. The domain of these sites looks very official, they are all reputable organizations. Then which one is the official format specification? And are they the complete version that cover all JPEG variants?

No: "can't be downloaded securely" means exactly that, without implying "the files contain viruses". The websites just don't support HTTPS, only HTTP - hence the transport is insecure. Why not consulting Wikipedia articles on that? JFIF: ITU-T Recommendation T.871 and ISO/IEC 10918-5; JPEG: CCITT, now ITU-T; Exif: JEIDA, JEITA, CIPA. Those all may vary wich each standard's version.
